# scrapy javascript with spalsh wont render page

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I want to crawl [this page](https://shenoto.com/album/46321?lang=en), I follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352423/scrapy-shell-and-scrapy-splash) to crawl it but it didn't render webpage. 
How can I fix it?
I use this:

```
scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://shenoto.com/album
/46321?lang=en&timeout=10&wait=0.5'
```

and simply

```
response.body
```

But it didn't render the page. and show only javascripts in page.
Actually I want to crawl "application/ld+json" part of that website as show in picture below.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoDxc.png)

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976331/issue-with-scraping-js-rendered-page-with-scrapy-and-splash)  and fix the render issue.

and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939247/scrapy-extract-ldjson)  to load ld-json.